# How to deal with a table view receiving an update to its data as it is being drawn?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a problem with my table views which is best explained with some pseduo code:

```
var flag = false

func onFlagEnabledNotification() {
    flag = true
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    if flag == true {
        return M
    } else {
        return N
    }


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCel {
if flag == true {
     stuff
} else {
    other stuff
```

`onFlagEnabledNotification()` is triggered by receiving a notification broadcast.

The problem I'm observing is that when `numberOfRowsInSection` is called and `flag` is false then N number of rows will be returned.
But then if `onFlagEnabledNotification()` gets called as the table is being displayed then `flag` is set to true and then the logic in `cellForRowAt` is now mismatching as it is expecting there to be M rows based on the value of flag.

I was surprised by this as I thought having the `reloadData()` in `onFlagEnabledNotification()` would prevent this problem - I thought this would trigger a new call to `numberOfRowsInSection` and thus there wouldn't be any mismatch imbalance, but this does not appear to be the case as after `onFlagEnabledNotification()` is called `cellForRowAt` still gets invoked before any call to `numberOfRowsInSection` does.

Comment: Try moving the setting of `flag` to inside the `async` call instead of before it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're showing additional data (assuming `M > N`) when the flag is turned on.  Instead of reloading all the data when the flag is toggled, I would use the `insertRows()` and `deleteRows()` methods.  Use the `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` methods to batch changes.

See the section in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview#symbols) on inserting, deleting, and moving cells.

Comment: But is it safe to call insertRows() etc. before the table view has completing displaying yet?  This update can occur as the OS is actively populating/displaying the table, not after that process has finished.